# xmlHttp string POST Headers issue

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

i am trying to pass a string through the XmlHttp method. Let me show you the code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="greetings">
                    You are voting out <b style="color: #00b0de;" id=roadiename></b>. Care to explain why?<br/><br/>
                    <textarea name="textarea" id="comment" cols="38" rows="7"></textarea><br>
                    <a href="#" id="postmsg" onclick='getMsg("#comment.val()")' ><img src="images/submit.gif" style="border: none; float:right; padding-top: 10px;padding-right: 10px;"/></a>
                </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function getMsg(msg)
{
    msgBox = msg;
}

Core.addEventListener(submit, "click", function(){Slide.send();});
```

**send function**

```
send: function()
    {   
        xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
        if (xmlHttp==null)
        {
            alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
            return;
        }

        var url="user_submit.php",
        data="vote="+value+"&sid="+Math.random();
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", data.length);
        xmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);
        xmlHttp.send( data );

        function stateChanged()
        {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
          {
          document.getElementById("greetings").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
        }

        function GetXmlHttpObject()
        {
        var objXMLHttp=null;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {
          objXMLHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else if (window.ActiveXObject)
          {
          objXMLHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        return objXMLHttp;
        }
    },
```

**after everything is said and done, this is the error Firebug is showing:**

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader]"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: http://localhost/roadies/JS/script.js :: anonymous :: line 96"  data: no]

Line 0
```

Comment: So you switched from jQuery to trying to do it manually?

Comment: yeah. jquery was killing me. ;-) i posted an update as you asked me to. can you take a look?

Comment: yeah ill take a look but the issue there was not sending the request nor getting the values from the request - it was an issue with your SQL.

Comment: i think you may be right. the issue may well be with the SQL. but the SQL part does not happen until late...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

You have to call `open`; before you can use the `setRequestHeaders`.

---

What is actually on line 96 of `http://localhost/roadies/JS/script.js`?

Comment: xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");

Comment: the exception is gone. no data still, though. i think i need a new user_submit.php file? or the SQL? i am going nuts.

Answer (score 0):

From the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader-method), and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers), the HTTP headers are actually "Content-Type" and "Content-Length" (note the uppercase second word).  Does changing the case make a difference?

Comment: Case doesn't matter. From the HTTP 1.1 Spec Section 4.2 - "Field names are case-insensitive" - http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html